# Firebase functions: Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a user to my Firestore database after Firebase Authentication. The error I'm getting is:

> Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.

Here is my function:

```js
const db = admin.firestore();

const createProfile = (userRecord, context) => {
  const { email, uid } = userRecord;
    
  return db
    .collection("Users")
    .doc({uid: uid})
    .set({email: email})
    .catch(console.error);
};

module.exports = {
  authOnCreate: functions.auth.user().onCreate(createProfile),
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doc()` requires that you pass just the string of the ID of the document.  You're passing an object, which is not valid.  If you want a document with the ID of `uid`, do this instead:

```
  return db
    .collection("Users")
    .doc(uid)
    .set({email: email})
    .catch(console.error);
```

Also, according to the API documentation, `email` could be undefined.  This would also cause an error, as Firestore doesn't accept undefined values.  You would have to check for that before adding it to the document.